# Setting RGB from white to black based on 24 hour timer

Tags: c#, math

I have a unique problem and I'm a bit stumped on how to do it.

I have a timer from 0-24 representing the hours in a day including decimal values.
I want to transform an RGB value from (0,0,0) black, to (255,255,255) white based on this number.
Full black should represent midday and full white should represent midnight and fade values in between.

So if the timer is 5.54 I'm moping to get a grey somewhere in the middle. I'm not sure if it's easily possible. Using c# is preferred but should be transferable between languages.

Edit: The timer resets to 0 and starts again in an endless loop.

So it needs to work like this with the top being white and bottom being black and 0 - 24 being the X axis.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the first thing you have to realise is that you've actually made the problem really easy for yourself by choosing a gray-scale gradient. This is because you only have to work out 1 value (0 - 255) and you can use that same value for R, G and B.

As to how to work out the value - that's also really simple! Your gradient runs from midday to midnight, so you just need to work out how many 256ths through that 12-hour period you are in.

There are 43200 seconds in that 12-hour period, so you just need to take the number of seconds after midday the current time represents, divide that by 43200 and then multiply it by 256 - you then have your R, G and B values.

In pseudo-code, it would look like:

```
var secondsAfterMidday = GetSecondsAfterMidday();
var colorValue = secondsAfterMidday / 43200 * 255;
return color(red: colorValue, green: colorValue, blue: colorValue);
```

A couple of classes you will likely want to use:

- [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0)
- [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0)

Comment: EDIT: Same issue, it clicks back to black after it rolls over from 11-12 or 23-0.

Comment: mySunHour = sunHour - 12;;
if(sunHour < 12) {
    mySunHour = 12 - sunHour;
} 
float secondsAfterMidday = (mySunHour) * (60 * 60);
float colorValue = secondsAfterMidday / 43200 * 255;
cl.SetColor(new Color32(colorValue,colorValue,colorValue,1));

Answer (score 1):

From the current number of seconds in the day, this returns a value between 0 and 255.

[image: GetLinearColor graph]

[WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%28+%28x+-+%28Quotient%5Bx%2C43200%5D*Remainder%5Bx%2C43200%5D*2%29+%29+%2F+43200%29+*+255%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%2286400%22)

```
static int MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 43200; // 12 hours (12*60*60)

public int GetLinearColor(int timeInSeconds)
{
    // Make sure the input loops around the 24 hour clock.
    timeInSeconds %= MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS*2;
    
    /*
        Seconds after 12:00 count in reverse to get:

        43200                     /\
                             /         \
                        /                   \
                   /                             \
            0 /                                       \
            
              00:00     06:00     12:00     18:00     00:00
    */
    
    if (timeInSeconds >= MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    {
        timeInSeconds = MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS - (timeInSeconds-MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS);        
    }
    
    // Scale timeInSeconds from 0 to 1
    double scale = timeInSeconds / (double)MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS;
    
    // Scale to color
    return (int)(255 * scale);
}
```

I've also added a second variant which curves (not quite like the bell-shape in your image but its close):

[image: GetCurvedColor graph]

[WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotvariable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22+-%3E+%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotlowerrange%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22plot%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%281+-+%28%28cos%28+%28+%28x+-+%28Quotient%5Bx%2C43200%5D*Remainder%5Bx%2C43200%5D*2%29+%29+%2F+43200%29+*+PI%29+%2B+1%29+%2F+2%29%29+*+255%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Plot%22%2C+%22plotupperrange%22%7D+-%3E%2286400%22)

```
public int GetCurvedColor(int timeInSeconds)
{
    // Make sure the input loops around the 24 hour clock.
    timeInSeconds %= MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS*2;
    
    /*
        Seconds after 12:00 count in reverse to get:

        43200                     /\
                             /         \
                        /                   \
                   /                             \
            0 /                                       \
            
              00:00     06:00     12:00     18:00     00:00
    */
    
    if (timeInSeconds >= MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    {
        timeInSeconds = MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS - (timeInSeconds-MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS);        
    }
    
    // Scale timeInSeconds from 0 to 1
    double scale = timeInSeconds / (double)MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS;
    
    // Convert scale to radians
    double radians = scale * Math.PI; // Use only the first half
    
    
    // Use first half of cosine from 1 to -1, flip it up side down and scale it from 0 to 1
    /*
        Cosine:
        
         1 --_                 _--
               \              /
                \            /
         0 -  -  |  -  -  - |-  - 
                  \        /
                   \_    _/
        -1          ----
        
        
        Flipped first half of cosine, scaled from 0 to 1
        
         1        _---
                /       
              _/          
         0 ---  -  -  -
    */
            
    double cos = Math.Cos(radians);
    
    double curvedScale = 1.0 - ((cos + 1.0) / 2.0);

    // Scale to color
    return (int)(255 * curvedScale);
}
```

**[edit]**

Also found a way to get the bell curve:

[image: GetBellColor graph]

[WolframAlpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Plot%22%2C%20%22plotvariable%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22Plot%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Plot%22%2C%20%22plotlowerrange%22%7D%20-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22plot%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Plot%22%2C%20%22plotfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22%281%2F%282%2B2*cosh%28%20%28%28%20%28x%20-%20%28Quotient%5Bx%2C43200%5D*Remainder%5Bx%2C43200%5D*2%29%20%29%20%2F%2043200%29%29*8-8%20%29%29%29%20*%204%20*%20255%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22Plot%22%2C%20%22plotupperrange%22%7D%20-%3E%2286400%22)

```
public int GetBellColor(int timeInSeconds)
{
    // Make sure the input loops around the 24 hour clock.
    timeInSeconds %= MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS*2;

    /*
        Seconds after 12:00 count in reverse to get:

        43200                     /\
                             /         \
                        /                   \
                   /                             \
            0 /                                       \

              00:00     06:00     12:00     18:00     00:00
    */

    if (timeInSeconds >= MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    {
        timeInSeconds = MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS - (timeInSeconds-MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS);        
    }

    // Scale timeInSeconds from 0 to 1
    double scale = timeInSeconds / (double)MID_DAY_IN_SECONDS;

    /*
        Hubbert curve (1/(2+2*cosh(x))):
        
        0.250           /-\
                        | |
                        | |
        0.125          /   \
                      |     |
                    _/       \_
        0.000 ___---           ---___
             -8   -4     0     4     8

    */

    // Use left side (-8 to 0) of Hubbert curve, scale up (from 0 to 1 instead of 0 to 0.25)
    double curvedScale =  (1.0/(2.0+2.0*Math.Cosh((scale*8)-8)))*4.0;

    // Scale to color
    return (int)(255 * curvedScale);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the answer (with 0 and 24hours case too), you can do like this :

```
        double hour = 0; // any value between 0 and 24
        int rgb = 0; 
        // prevent DivideByZero for 0 and 24 hours
        if(hour > 0 && hour < 24)
        {
            double rgbDivider = hour <= 12 ? 12 / hour : 12/(24 - hour);
            rgb = (int)Math.Round(255 / rgbDivider, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // Round result number into int
        }
```

Comment: Hey, this works great up until it ticks over from 23.99 to 0. Then it snaps back to black. Sorry didn't explain the loop in the question